# Dynamically update the configmap values

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have following configmaps

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  application.properties: |+
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  keyN: valueN
```

Configmaps is mounted to pod and works fine.

My requirement is to programmatically  replace the value for some of the keys.
I can run shell/python script and I can run any kubectl command.

Comment: do you have a sample example with the required changes and the output for the same?

Comment: also, did you try anything? `kubectl patch` should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Keep in mind, that the application also has to re-read the properties after they have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kubectl patch` command to update K8s resources.

```
kubectl patch configmap/test \
  --type=json \
  '-p=[{"op": "replace","path": "/data/key1", "value": "test1"}]'
```

**An important point to note as mentioned by Henry is that the application also has to re-read the properties after they have been changed.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bash` script to dynamically replace some keys and values in your `ConfigMaps`.

I've created simple bash script to illustrate how it may works on my kubeadm cluster v1.20:

```
#!/bin/bash

keyName="key1"
value="value100"

read -p 'Enter ConfigMap name: ' configmapName

if kubectl get cm ${configmapName} 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "ConfigMap name to modify: ${configmapName}"
else
        echo "ERROR: bad ConfigMap name"
        exit 1
fi

kubectl patch cm ${configmapName} -p "{\"data\":{\"${keyName}\":\"${value}\"}}"
```

In the above example you need to pass `ConfigMap` name and set what you want to modify.
In addition you may want to pass `keyName` and `value` values as command line arguments in similar way to `configmapName` value.

You can see an example of how the above script works:

```
root@kmaster:~# ./replaceValue.sh 
Enter ConfigMap name: test
ConfigMap name to modify: test
configmap/test patched
root@kmaster:~# kubectl describe cm test
Name:         test
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
application.properties:
----

key1:
----
value100
key2:
----
value2
keyN:
----
valueN
Events:  <none>
root@kmaster:~#
```

Note: If you want to use `kubectl replace` instead of `kubectl patch`, you can use below command (e.g. `sourceValue="key1: value1"` and `destinationValue="key1: value100"`)

```
kubectl get cm ${configmapName} -o yaml | sed "s/${sourceValue}/${destinationValue}/" | kubectl replace -f -
```

Comment: @pythonhmmm Does this answer your question ?